# Mapping a large number to a unique number using MOD operation

Tags: algorithm, math, integer-division, modulo

Let the Roots of a first degree polynomial( Q(x) ) be x0 = -b/a. Since the range of the variable a and b is large, x0 can be large as well for it to be stored in a variable(x0).

so, it is converted to some unique number using some operation with **mod**

`int x0 = mul(mod - b, rev(a));`

problem link: [hackerank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack45/challenges/polynomial-division)

Can someone please explain how this line of code works and the math behind this operation?

the whole code-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define forn(i,n) for (int i = 0; i < int(n); ++i)
typedef long long ll;
const int inf = int(1e9) + int(1e5);
const ll infl = ll(2e18) + ll(1e10);

const int mod = 1e9 + 7;

int udd(int &a, int b) {
    a += b;
    if (a >= mod)
        a -= mod;
    return a;
}

int add(int a, int b) {
    return udd(a, b);
}

int mul(ll a, ll b) {
    return a * b % mod;
}

//============didnt understand this step
int bin(int a, int d) {
    int b = 1;
    while (d) {
        if (d & 1)
            b = mul(b, a);
        d >>= 1;
        a = mul(a, a);
    }
    return b;
}

int rev(int a) {
    assert(a != 0);
    return bin(a, mod - 2);
}



const int maxn = 100100;
int px[maxn];
int c[maxn];

struct Fenwick {
    int a[maxn];
    int t[maxn];

    void set(int pos, int val) {
        int delta = add(val, mod - a[pos]);
        a[pos] = val;
        delta = mul(delta, px[pos]);
        for (int i = pos; i < maxn; i |= i + 1) {
            udd(t[i], delta);
        }
    }

    int get(int r) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = r - 1; i >= 0; i = (i & (i + 1)) - 1)
            udd(res, t[i]);
        return res;
    }

    int get(int l, int r) {
        return add(get(r), mod - get(l));
    }
} fw;

int main() {
    #ifdef LOCAL
    assert(freopen("test.in", "r", stdin));
    #endif
    int n, a, b, q;
    cin >> n >> a >> b >> q;

    //========what does this line do?
    int x0 = mul(mod - b, rev(a));
    px[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        px[i] = mul(px[i - 1], x0);
    forn (i, n) {
        cin >> c[i];
        fw.set(i, c[i]);
    }
    forn (i, q) {
        int t, a, b;
        cin >> t >> a >> b;
        if (t == 1) {
            fw.set(a, b);
        } else {
            ++b;
            int s = fw.get(a, b);
            if (x0 == 0)
                s = fw.a[a];
            cout << (s == 0 ? "Yes" : "No") << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bin` is the halving-and-squaring implementation for the (in this case modular) power function `a^d % mod`, so that the modular inverse in `rev` can be computed via the little theorem of Fermat.